# Jacobson radical of a subring

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be any ring and $B$ be its subring. 
Is it true that $J(A)\cap B\subseteq J(B)$?

If not, is it true that for a finitely generated algebra $A$ over a local commutative noetherian ring $\mathcal{O}$ and a subalgebra $B$ of $A$, 
$J(A)\cap B\subseteq J(B)$?

I first tried to note that $J(A)\cap B$ is a nilpotent ideal of $B$, so it must be included in $J(B)$, but then I realized $J(A)$ is nilpotent for left artinian rings, but not in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not true. Take any polynomial ring $K[T]$ over a field. Then $J(K[T]) = \{0\}$. Now you want the left hand side to be nonzero, so you take $A$ as the localization of $K[T]$ at the maximal ideal $(T)$ and we have $J(K[T]_{(T)}) \cap K[T] = (T)$.

Comment: Is this a counter example to the first sentence or the second sentence? Could you please recommend a source to learn about localization for non-commutative rings?

Comment: @AgentSmith I had commutative rings in mind.  Any field is a local ring and both $K[T]$, $K[T]_{(T)} = K[T, 1/T]$ are finitely generated over the local ring $K$. So this is a counterexample to the second claim and therefore also to the first one. I don't know about  localization in noncommutative rings but Joseph Rotman's Introduction to Homological Algebra is a good book that focuses on the commutative case. It also talks about the Jacobson for general rings.